# Merge or Combine Multiple Rows Records to Single Column Record with Comma delimiters SNOWSQL

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I know this question has been asked before here, but for SNOWSQL in particular, is there a function similar to 'STUFF' to combine two values into a single record? I basically want to be able to use this query:

```
               SELECT ISSUE_ID,
               STUFF((SELECT ', ' + AFFECTS_VERSION
               FROM VW_JIRA_ISSUES
               WHERE ISSUE_ID = T.ISSUE_ID
               FOR XML PATH (''), type) ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')               
               AS VERSIONS
               FROM VW_JIRA_ISSUES
               GROUP BY ISSUE_ID
```

Comment: I actually ended up using Snowflake's LISTAGG FUNCTION: `select issue_id, 
        listagg(AFFECTS_VERSION, ', ') within group (order by issue_id desc)
        FROM VW_JIRA_ISSUES

      group by issue_id`

Answer (score 0):

How about Snowflake's INSERT() function? I understand it is basically the same as MySQL's INSERT() function which in turn is the equivalent of STUFF() in SQL Server.

References:

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/insert.html
- https://database.guide/whats-the-mysql-equivalent-of-stuff-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

select issue_id, 
        listagg(AFFECTS_VERSION, ', ') within group (order by issue_id desc)
        FROM VW_JIRA_ISSUES
    group by issue_id